# Cache for nondurable objects in datanucleus

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, isis

I have several nondurable entities that are mapped via datanucleus on View's and i want to load them into memory on startup in cache and reload once per day, but datanucleus says that he can't provide caching for nondurable objects. Does anyone now the way to implement caching in this situatuion via datanucleus?

Comment: A nondurable object has no "id", so how do you look-up something with no "id" ?

Comment: You might want to ask Andy Jefferson on the DataNucleus gitter channel ... https://gitter.im/datanucleus/Lobby